# CSS Images with flex inline style. How change form to block according resolution?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

How do this ? I would like to create div with inline flex and when user change resolution, this div change display to block. I try many ways but I don't know why its didn't work.

```
    <div
        style="text-align: center; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 400px;">


        <div style="">
            <img style="text-align: center;" src="laptop.png">
            <p>logo</p>
        </div>

        <div style="margin-left: 120px; margin-right: 120px;">
            <img src="laptop.png">
            <p>logo</p>
        </div>

        <div style="">
            <img src="laptop.png">
            <p>logo</p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

codepen.io/Remax166/pen/EXomZK

Thanks for help :) !

Comment: If you mean block by displaying as column then add flex-wrap: wrap; to the parent.

Comment: Yes but how change this when resolution change to mobile? From inline to block?

Flex working normal but when i change browser resolution then one of block hide.

Comment: do you want to show three blocks in a row on desktop and one block in a row in mobile?

Comment: Well if you add what I told you it will wrap into a column once the viewport is resized. If you do not want that approach you can use media queries and depending on the device size change that flex into a block. You will need to put everything inside a class to target the element. See this:  https://jsfiddle.net/h7oxuhx9/

Comment: Okey its working :) I have to learn about media queries and practise this. Thanks for help guys !